# remote validator in jquery bootstrapValidator

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap-3

The remote validation is not working. It always shows as The username is not valid. Im new to this jquery validation. So can any one please tell what the error is.

```
username: {
                        message: 'The username is not valid',
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The username is required and cannot be empty'
                            },
                            stringLength: {
                                min: 6,
                                max: 30,
                                message: 'The username must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                            },
                            regexp: {
                                regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                                message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                            },
                            remote: {
                                url: 'remote.jsp',
                                type: "post",
                                async: false,
                                data:
                                        {
                                            username: function(validator)
                                            {
                                                return $('#defaultForm :input[name="username"]').val();

                                            }
                                        },
                                message: 'The username is not available',
                            },
```

In the backend I'm using JSP and code is:

```
    ResultSet rs;
    Boolean flag = true;

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    rs = st.executeQuery("select * from members where user_name = '" + username + "'");
    if (rs.next()) {
        flag = false;
        out.print("false");    //already exist  

    } else {
        flag = true;
        out.print("true");   // not exist 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using servlet

```
username: {
            message: 'The username is not valid',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {},
                stringLength: {
                    min: 6,
                    max: 20
                },
                regexp: {
                    regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/
                },

                remote: {
                url: './CheckUsernameServlet',
                type: 'POST',
                delay: 2000  

                }

            }
        },
```

in servlet code

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    String email=request.getParameter("username");
    if(userDAO.validateEmail(email)){

        try {
            json.put("valid",true);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {

        try {
            json.put("valid",false);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    out.print(json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the code 
write above code

```
 username: {
      message: 'The username is not valid',
      validators: {
                notEmpty: {},
                stringLength: {
                min: 6,
                max: 20
            },
                regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/
            },

                remote: {
                url: './CheckUsernameServlet',
                type: 'POST',
                delay: 2000                
             }
         }
  },
```

and

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.json.JSONException" %> 
<%@ page import="org.json.JSONObject" %>  
<% 
    ResultSet rs=null;
    Boolean flag = true;
    Statement st=null;
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    rs = st.executeQuery("select * from members where user_name = '" + username + "'");
    if (rs.next()){
        flag = false;
        flag = false;
        json.put("valid",false); 
    } 
    else {
        flag = true;
        json.put("valid",true);
    }
    out.print(json);
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer After 1 year**

What I have done is I just change the return json to a valid Json data.Cuz the answer above is correct but its not returning the valid Json data.

```
    public class RegistrationEmailCheck extends HttpServlet {
      protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/json");

  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
String availEmail = request.getParameter("email");
System.out.println(availEmail);
String SQL = "SELECT email FROM login WHERE email='" + availEmail + "'";
Connection con = DBInfo.getConn();
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;

try {
    st = con.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery(SQL);


    if (rs.next()) {

        out.print("{\"valid\" : false }");
        json.put("valid", false);
        System.out.println("false");


    } else {

        out.print("{\"valid\" : true }");
        json.put("valid", true);
        System.out.println("true");


    }


} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {

    out.close();
     }



   }


 }
```

And now everything is working fine.